# How to set fixed table layout or grid layout?

Tags: android

I'm making a simple game for myself, something like Sea Battle, and I want to set fixed 10x10 field.
Tried GridLayout - can't set number of rows
Tried GridView - gives me error with compatibly library

What should I use to make fixed 10x10 field, supporting clicks on cells?
Something like this:

[image]

Comment: You can use android:numColumns="10" in your Gridview

Comment: And what about **rows** ?

Comment: @ kondra007 :- You can't fix the rows in gridview . If you want to fix rows. Check Gridlayout or Tablelayout.